# Listview not displaying any items

Tags: android, arrays, listview, azure-sql-database

I am creating a listview where i get my items from my azure database through an SQL query with a where statement. My code runs but when i try to search something a `toast` shows at the bottom of my screen with `[]`, Here is my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.srail, container, false);
    search = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    Esearch = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.srch);
    list = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.raill);

    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckLogin checkLogin = new CheckLogin();
            checkLogin.execute("");

            List<Map<String,String>> MyData = new ArrayList();

            String[] fromwhere = { "NAME","PRICE","RANGE","SUPPLIER","SIZE" };

            int[] viewswhere = {R.id.Name_txtView , R.id.price_txtView,R.id.Range_txtView,R.id.size_txtView,R.id.supplier_txtView};

            ADAhere = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), MyData,R.layout.list_products, fromwhere, viewswhere);

            list.setAdapter(ADAhere);


            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    HashMap<String,Object> obj=(HashMap<String,Object>)ADAhere.getItem(position);
                    String ID=(String)obj.get("A");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}


public class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String z = "";
    Boolean isSuccess = false;

    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Searching...",
                "Listview Loading! Please Wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
        progress.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (isSuccess) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Search Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            //finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String Search = search.getText().toString();


        if (Search.trim().equals(""))
            z = "Please Search something";
        else {
            List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
            data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            try {
                ConnectionHelper conStr = new ConnectionHelper();
                connect = conStr.connectionclass();        // Connect to database
                if (connect == null) {
                    z = "Check Your Internet Access!";
                } else {
                    // Change below query according to your own database.
                    String query = "select * from cc_rail where rail_name='" + Search.toString() + "' OR RAIL_UNIT_PRICE= '" + Search.toString() + "' OR RAIL_RANGE= '" + Search.toString() + "' OR RAIL_SUPPLIER='" + Search.toString() + "' OR RAIL_SIZE='" + Search.toString() + "'";
                    Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        datanum.put("NAME", rs.getString("RAIL_NAME"));

                        datanum.put("PRICE", rs.getString("RAIL_UNIT_PRICE"));

                        datanum.put("RANGE", rs.getString("RAIL_RANGE"));

                        datanum.put("SUPPLIER", rs.getString("RAIL_SUPPLIER"));

                        datanum.put("SIZE", rs.getString("RAIL_SIZE"));
                        data.add(datanum);
                    }


                    z = " successful";
                    isSuccess = true;
                    connect.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                isSuccess = false;
                z = ex.getMessage();
            }

            return String.valueOf(data);
        }
        return z;
    }



   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using this `MyData` variable as the data source for you adapter:

```
List<Map<String,String>> MyData = new ArrayList();
...
ADAhere = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), MyData,R.layout.list_products, fromwhere, viewswhere);
 ...
 list.setAdapter(ADAhere);
```

And yet you're not adding anything neither to the direct data source `MyData` nor through the adapter `ADAhere`.

**EDIT:**

What you can do to fix this is, make your data variable global (move it to before onCreateView():

```
List<Map<String,String>> MyData = new ArrayList();
```

Then inside your asynctask you call add to add data to it:

```
while (rs.next()) {
                        Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        datanum.put("NAME", rs.getString("RAIL_NAME"));

                        datanum.put("PRICE", rs.getString("RAIL_UNIT_PRICE"));

                        datanum.put("RANGE", rs.getString("RAIL_RANGE"));

                        datanum.put("SUPPLIER", rs.getString("RAIL_SUPPLIER"));

                        datanum.put("SIZE", rs.getString("RAIL_SIZE"));
                        MyData.add(datanum);
                    }
                     ADAhere.notifyDatasetChanged()
```

Then simply call ADAhere.notifyDatasetChanged() when you're done loading data into MyData.

Comment: so can i get the fix? because im still lost

Comment: just one more question, where do i put the notifyDatasetChanged()  because i have being trying and still getting errors? sorry still new at android coding

Comment: you can call ADAhere.notifyDatasetChanged() right after the while is finished

Comment: Declare your ADAhere as **BaseAdapter ADAhere**

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: THe problem is that SimpleAdapter doesn't have that method. Let's try calling **list.setAdapter(ADAhere);** instead.

Comment: have a look at this code in the question its still my code with your fixes however it still does not work. thanks for all the help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50000961/cannot-resolve-symbol-notifydatasetchanged